# Conditional Formatting formula for if cell begins with number list item ("1. ", "2. " etc)

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, formula, conditional-formatting

I want to conditional format a few things in my Google Sheet (this applies to excel too though).

**Q1: Highlight any cell that begins with a number point.**

Such as "1. " or "2. " etc. So 'Number, dot, space'. My working formula currently is:

```
=OR(LEFT(C1,3) = "1. ", LEFT(C1,3) = "2. ", LEFT(C1,3) = "3. ", LEFT(C1,3) = "4. ", LEFT(C1,3) = "5. ")
```

But I'm sure there's a REGEX way of doing this, right? Instead of manually doing an OR condition for each number? (The length is unknown, I just stopped at 5 in the formula for an example).

---

**Q2: Formatting any of a list of strings**

How can I detect if the cell 'starts with' (or 'is exactly') either "Apples", "Oranges", or "Mangos". Something like:

```
=OR(C1={"Apples", "Oranges", "Mangos"})
```

The above is only ever highlighting the first in that list, regardless of if its Apples or Oranges etc.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following in `custom formula is`

```
=REGEXMATCH(G2,"^\d+. ")
```

[image]

*(do adjust ranges to your needs)*

Comment: Please use a new post for your second question. It needs a completely different approach.